# vector<string> on heap, using an initializer list?

Tags: c++, vector

All the examples I can find of populating a vector using an initializer list look seem to all be creating a vector on the stack:

```
vector<string> v = {"1","2","3"}
```

I would like to achieve something like:

```
vector<string>* v = new vector<string>(){"1","2","3"};
```

but I get compiler errors. Is it possible to declare a vector on the heap using an initialiser list?

Comment: Hmm. *Why* do you want to create a vector on the heap? Regardless, *if* you do so, don’t store the result in a raw pointer. That’s an absolute no-go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove parentheses:

```
vector<string>* v = new vector<string>{"1","2","3"};
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/4mTwmh). Note that this does not work prior to C++11.

Also note that although the vector in your example is created on the stack, it's content is still created on the heap. If you want to have the content stored on the stack as well and the size of the content is known at compile time, use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: I get an error just before the first open curly bracket, saying it is expecting a semi-colon. I am using VS2012 compiler.

Comment: @user997112 That's because VS2012's C++ is not fully C++11 - compliant. Here is a [chart showing that the compiler does not fully support initializer lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: As a workaround, if your compiler does support initialization lists in the stack but not in the heap you can do: `vector<string>* v; { vector<string> tmp = { "1", "2" }; v = new vector<string>(std::move(tmp)); }`

Comment: @user997112 You need v14 of ICC for full support ([link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler)). v12 and earlier have no support; v13 has partial support.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use one of these:

1. `std::vector<std::string>* v = new std::vector<std::string>({"1","2","3"});`
2. `std::vector<std::string>* v = new std::vector<std::string>{"1","2","3"};`